# start date = now() in task subpanel of accounts module(detail view)

Tags: task, sugarcrm, overriding

In accounts detail view inside activities sub-panel, create task(quick create)

I need to set start_date = now() [i mean the current time].

I have the JavaScript to find current time but i can't use this code to patch it up on the start_date field.

One suggestion i got was of overriding the quick create task and creating new field where JS is included in the code...but i was not able to implement it. Please help.

Comment: Please give more details. The name of field you want to pre-fill, the name of module. Which version of CRM do you have? You could try to accomplish it by using Dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you are just doing this for this one view, you can do a subclass of the QuickCreate view to handle. Add this in the custom/modules/Tasks/views/view.quickcreate.php file ( you may need to create the directory and file )

```
<?php

require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.quickcreate.php');

class TasksViewQuickcreate extends ViewQuickcreate
{
    public function preDisplay() 
    {
        parent::preDisplay();
        if( !$this->_isDCForm && empty($this->bean->date_start)) {
            $_REQUEST['date_start'] = $GLOBALS['timedate']->now();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: It didnt work....:(
there are two fields....(1) date_start_date..the actual field (2) date_start..the hidden field...which i guess is used for form submittion....still the code stands valid....? or need i do something more...?

Comment: You may need to change it to whatever the form field would be.